# How do I convert unicode code to string in Python?

Tags: python, unicode

One of my string variables contains unicode code `\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627`.
I want to convert it to a string and see what characters were encoded by it.

Is it possible and how can I do it in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just an internal representation. If you print it, you will get what you want:

```
>>> print("\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627")
رَجا
```

In short, this is how Python stores the characters `رَ` and `جا`. If you tell Python to print them, you'll see them converted back to their human-readable form.

Answer (score 3):

Decode using [`unicode_escape` encoding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings):

In Python 2.x:

```
>>> text = r'\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627'
>>> print(text)
\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627
>>> print(text.decode('unicode-escape'))
رَجا
```

---

In Python 3.x:

```
>>> text = r'\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627'
>>> print(text.encode().decode('unicode-escape'))
رَجا
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print u"\u0631\u064e\u062c\u0627"
رَجا
```